# If there are 6 teams in a group and they all play each other once, how many unique group standings can there be? Is there a formula?

Tags: combinations

So for instance, if there are 2 teams in a group then there are 2 different possible outcomes but only 1 unique way the standings can look:

1-0
0-1

For 3 teams, there are 2 options:

2-0
1-1
0-2

and:

1-1

1-1

1-1

Now how I can keep listing out the possibilities for however many teams but is there a formula that can help me? For instance for a group of 6 teams, how many unique standings can there be?

Comment: Can you explain the **standings**  given for $3$ teams specifying $A, B, C$?

Comment: Judging by your examples, there can only be wins and losses, so there are no draws.  Is that correct?

Comment: There are no draws so for 3 teams, the standings will look like one of the two standings above